# App Inventor Runtime Error

Tags: runtime-error, app-inventor

I'm trying to make a very simple BMI calculator using App Inventor 2, and here is my designer screen, code and Error Message:

[image: screenshots].

I can't find out the bug or anything might cause this. It does work and calculate properly! If I just tapped on the screen, the error message may disappear. And the error message won't show up if I remove all "if" blocks.

Here is my project(.aia file): [through dropbox](https://goo.gl/j9rQ0G), could anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Your blocks look fine. Drag new *if* blocks from the tool bar and use the new blocks instead to see if that helps...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work :(  ...sad

Comment: I create a new project with the same structure and the same code, and this time it works properly, no more errors.... Very strange...

Comment: Unknown Error AGAIN...

Answer (score 1):

I have take my time to test the code. Everything is working fine. By the way, you also can round off the result. Yet, it may be not so accurate if we want to know someone body mass index. ;)

[image]